# execute animation when animation ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

i want to execute the "flip" animation when the "anim" animation ends.
i want that the fish i created will start move to left then do the flip ans will swim to right again...

here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TxC5y/7/

```
function anim() {
    $('.fish_wrap').animate({
     "left": "-90px"}, 5000);

}

anim();

function flip() {
      $('.fish_wrap').transition({
      perspective: '100px',
      rotateY: '180deg'
});
}

flip();
```

Comment: What is `transition` in `$('.fish_wrap').transition`?

Comment: @j08691 took it from here: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: @alonblack At least in your fiddle, you haven't included that library.

Comment: @JamesMontagne what does it mean? "to include the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a callback to `.animate`, which runs on completion:

```
function anim() {
    $('.fish_wrap').animate({
     "left": "-90px"}, 5000, flip);
}
```

The callback syntax for `.transition` is slightly different:

```
function flip() {
    $('.fish_wrap').transition({
      perspective: '100px',
      rotateY: '180deg',
      complete: back            // reverse the animation
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3XZ59/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `complete` callback in the [jQuery animate call](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
function anim(callWhenDone) {
    $('.fish_wrap').animate({"left": "-90px"}, 5000, callWhenDone);
}

anim(flip);

function flip() {
      $('.fish_wrap').transition({
      perspective: '100px',
      rotateY: '180deg'
});
}
```